# How do I use a crate from another crate without explicitly defining a new dependency in my project?

Tags: rust

I want to use the [`dijkstra`](https://docs.rs/pathfinding/0.1.11/pathfinding/fn.dijkstra.html) function from the `pathfinding` crate:

```
pub fn dijkstra<N, C, FN, IN, FS>(
    start: &N, 
    neighbours: FN, 
    success: FS
) -> Option<(Vec<N>, C)> 
where
    N: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    C: Zero + Ord + Copy,
    FN: Fn(&N) -> IN,
    IN: IntoIterator<Item = (N, C)>,
    FS: Fn(&N) -> bool,
```

To use it I need to implement the `Zero` trait from the [`num_traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.1.37/num_traits/identities/trait.Zero.html) crate. But how can I import `Zero`? An obvious way is to add `extern crate num_traits;` into my crate and fix my `Cargo.toml` appropriately. But in doing so, I have to watch a dependency of a dependency, which is not good.

Can I somehow implement `Zero` without explicit dependency on the  [`num_traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.1.37/num_traits/identities/trait.Zero.html) crate, like below?

```
use pathfinding::num_traits::Zero;
```

Comment: Some crates indeed expose the internal `num_traits` module publicly. It might be that the best thing to do here is to propose that in the pathfinding repository.

Comment: @E_net4: pathfinding 0.1.12 has been released with your proposed change. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the original intent of importing non-exposed dependencies from a crate (such as `pathfinding`) into a dependent project, that is currently not allowed. If a dependency is not re-exported by the crate, that makes it more of an implementation detail than part of the API. Allowing a dependent to access any "sub-dependency" would therefore be catastrophic.

In this case however, since `num_traits` is clearly used in the crate's public API, it also makes sense for the dependent to have access to it. As it is, you are expected to add the dependency in your own project, while taking care to keep a compatible version. Otherwise, cargo might end up building duplicate dependencies.

```
[dependencies]
num_traits = "0.1"
```

In order to avoid this, `pathfinding` would benefit from exporting its own `num_traits`, as below. [PR #6](https://github.com/samueltardieu/pathfinding/pull/6) was created for this purpose, and has been merged into version 0.1.12 (thanks, @SamuelTardieu).

```
pub extern crate num_traits;
```

With that done, you can now do exactly as written at the end of your question:

```
use pathfinding::num_traits::Zero;
```