# Referencing Gfx back-end types from crates within front-end crates

Tags: rust

I'm following [a tutorial on the gfx library](https://wiki.alopex.li/LearningGfx). The following code is used to init the windowing system and it returns various bits using implicitly typed binding.

```
let (window, mut device, mut factory, color_view, mut depth_view) =
    gfx_glutin::init::<ColorFormat, DepthFormat>(windowbuilder, contextbuilder, &events_loop);
```

For the sake of readability I decided to try and extract the drawing code that is part of the tutorial into it's own function.

```
fn draw_triangle(factory: &Factory) {
    let mut encoder: gfx::Encoder<_, _> = factory.create_command_buffer().into();
    const TRIANGLE: [Vertex; 3] = [
        Vertex {
            pos: [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
            color: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        },
        Vertex {
            pos: [0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
            color: [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        },
        Vertex {
            pos: [0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
            color: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
        },
    ];
    //Identity Matrix
    const TRANSFORM: Transform = Transform {
        transform: [
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
        ],
    };

    let (vertex_buffer, slice) = factory.create_vertex_buffer_with_slice(&TRIANGLE, ());
    let transform_buffer = factory.create_constant_buffer(1);
    let data = pipe::Data {
        vbuf: vertex_buffer,
        transform: transform_buffer,
        out: color_view.clone(),
    };
    //Put in main loop before swap buffers and device clean-up method
    encoder.clear(&color_view, BLACK); //clear the framebuffer with a color(color needs to be an array of 4 f32s, RGBa)
    encoder.update_buffer(&data.transform, &[TRANSFORM], 0); //update buffers
    encoder.draw(&slice, &pso, &data); // draw commands with buffer data and attached pso
    encoder.flush(&mut device); // execute draw commands
}
```

The problem here is that `Factory` (passed in from the first code fragment) does not exist within the scope of this file, and in fact belongs to a crate that exists within the gfx_glutin_window crate.

The compiler is happy with this being implicitly defined in the first fragment of code, but it looks like I can't explicitly refer it without declaring a hard dependency on said crate.  (i.e. I can't get at it through the gfx_glutin_window crate).

I'm not sure if I'm just completely missing the mark here, or whether this is by design.  Though I can imagine a scenario where project dependencies clash with transient dependencies in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, it's true that `gfx_window_glutin` would probably benefit from re-exporting the data types, since its public API is effectively returning instances of those types. This has happened before in other crates such as [`pathfinder` re-exporting `num_traits`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44876113/1233251), and one could propose something similar to `gfx_window_glutin` by filing an issue at the main repository.

**On the other hand**, it is actually recommended to build code that is generic over the back-end implementation of Gfx. Both [`Factory`](https://docs.rs/gfx/0.16.1/gfx/trait.Factory.html) and [`Resources`](https://docs.rs/gfx/0.16.1/gfx/trait.Resources.html) are trait types which encapsulate the underlying implementation, so you should use these constraints in your code instead.

```
use gfx::{Factory, Resources};

fn draw_triangle<R, F>(factory : &F)
where
    R: Resources,
    F: Factory<R>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant (I was afraid this was going to be a pattern in rust) the latter solution is definitely more robust.  Is it considered good practice across rust to use Traits in these situations?  Thanks.  Oh and thanks for clearing up my question.

Comment: @user975391 When feasible, generalizing is frequently a good idea. For instance, if you choose to use the piston2d-graphics API over Gfx, you are still advised to make code generic over [`Graphics`](https://docs.rs/piston2d-graphics/0.23.0/graphics/trait.Graphics.html). When using textures, which only work for a specific, one can [assign the `Texture` associated type](https://docs.rs/piston2d-graphics/0.23.0/graphics/trait.Graphics.html#associatedtype.Texture) to the intended texture type.