# How to use dependencies from other projects in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have listed a package as my dependency. That package has several other dependencies which I want to use. How do I do that?

Here is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[dependencies.substrate-api-client]
git = "https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client"
```

Here is how I am importing a module:

```
use clap::{load_yaml, App};
```

Here is the error that I am facing:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `clap`
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 | use clap::{load_yaml, App};
   |     ^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `clap`
```

Even though, the dependency that I listed above(`substrate-api-client`) [is having `clap` as a dependency itself](https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L108).

I also attempted to use `extern crate`:

```
extern crate clap;
use clap::{load_yaml, App};
```

but it didn't work either and produced the following error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `clap`
```

Comment: Just because your dependencies have a dependency, doesn't make that a direct dependency of your own code. You need to explicitly declare a dependency on any crates that you use yourself.

Comment: You need to list your dependencies explicitly. Consider the scenario where the library you’re using stops using clap internally. Would it make sense if your program could break if a dependency’s internal implemention changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876113/how-do-i-use-a-crate-from-another-crate-without-explicitly-defining-a-new-depend).

However, it should be noted that a crate's dependencies are it's own unless explicitly chosen to be exposed. This *is* a good approach. If you were able to rely on `clap` from `substrate-api-client` for your own purposes, your application may fail to compile if `substrate-api-client` chooses to update the version of `clap` to one which contains breaking changes (you have not set the tag / branch of your dependency in Cargo.toml).

Comment: Do not answer duplicates. Instead, vote to close the question as a duplicate. Duplicating content makes it more difficult to maintain accurate and up-to-date answers.