# Use dependency of a dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

*Note: This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876113/how-do-i-use-a-crate-from-another-crate-without-explicitly-defining-a-new-depend) but not quite the same. I am fine with having to declare an explicit dependency and I'd even prefer directly using `use sha1`. The question here is more about versioning.*

Let's say in `Cargo.toml` I add a dependency to a specific version of a crate:

```
[dependencies]
mysql = "21.0.2"
```

In `Cargo.lock` I can see that `mysql` depends on the `sha1` crate (which isn't re-exported) and as the dependencies tree was generated, `sha1 0.6.0` was added to the `Cargo.lock` file. I want to use the `sha1` crate in my project as well, so I need to add it to `Cargo.toml`. How can I specify that I want to use the `sha1` version that is already available? I *don't* want Cargo to add an extra dependency to, say, `sha1 0.6.1` and so end up having 2 separate trees of `sha1` dependencies.

I also realize it's quite possible I could already have 2+ `sha` dependencies with different versions, coming from other crates I've added to my `Cargo.toml` file. So it would be perfect if I could basically say "use the latest of the already available versions of `sha`".

Is that possible?

Comment: You might want to check out the Rust Cargo book on [dependency resolution](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html). In cases as simple as a patch version bump, the compiler would know to use that as a common dependency between the two consumers. In more complicated cases, you can inspect the effective dependency tree using `cargo tree -d`.

Comment: You can specify the dependency as `sha1 = "*"`, which I believe `cargo` interprets as you'd like: it'll pick the latest one in the current dependency tree (or if not used by any dependency, just the latest from crates.io). I should say this isn't *really* recommended; it makes it unclear from the `Cargo.toml` which version you're using and a `"*"` dependency will prevent you from publishing your crate, but it can be fine for toy projects.